# How do i use the "Publish TAP Results" plugin on Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, tap, jenkins-2

I would like to use the "[Publish TAP results](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TAP+Plugin)" plugin on Jenkins 2.0 pipeline.
[image]

I'm not sure of the equivalent Groovy script for the same. Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This support was added to the TAP plugin 2.0 (2016-08-20).

Usage:
`step([$class: "TapPublisher", testResults: "**/target/tap-unit.log"])`

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34000

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for the pipeline, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34000.

But you can create on GitHub a pull request implementing that feature.