# Can you parse TAP format using Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, tap

I'm trying to parse the output from a BATS script (https://github.com/gaia-adm/docker-bench-test) which outputs into TAP format. I've modified the scripts slightly to cover CIS 1.13 instead of 1.11, but I don't know how to make Jenkins Pipeline handle that output.

I know there is a Jenkins plugin for TAP format, but I don't believe this works with Jenkins Pipeline Groovy scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> @Grab will work only if you jenkins has access to the internet

**workspace/job_name/tap.groovy**

```
@Grab(group='org.tap4j', module='tap4j', version='4.2.1')

import org.tap4j.consumer.TapConsumerFactory

def parse(def src){
    return TapConsumerFactory.makeTap13Consumer().load(src)
}

return this
```

**workspace/job_name/test.tap**

```
1..3
ok 1 - no error
not ok 2 - io error
ok 3 - no error
```

**Pipeline script**

```
node{
    def tap = load 'tap.groovy'
    tap = tap.parse( readFile('test.tap') )
    echo  "Number of tests found : ${tap.getNumberOfTestResults()}"
    echo  "Test Set failed?      : ${tap.containsNotOk()}"
}
```

**Output**

```
Number of tests found : 3
Test Set failed?      : true
```

The object returned by `tap.parse()`: [org.tap4j.model.TestSet](http://tap4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/tap4j/model/TestSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

With the tap plugin installed I was able to get my declarative pipeline script to display test results from tap files with the following command:

```
stage('publish test results') {
    steps {
        step([$class: "TapPublisher", testResults: "**/reports/*.tap"])
    }
}
```

[How do i use the "Publish TAP Results" plugin on Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405539/how-do-i-use-the-publish-tap-results-plugin-on-jenkins-2-0-pipeline)